# React-redux: mapDispatchToProps does not dispatch action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning redux and I am trying to learn by creating a personal project. The idea is to create a recipe app in which the users can view recipes, save their favorite recipes, and export their favorite recipes to a shopping list.

For rendering the recipes I use two components. One component is a single recipe, the other component maps the different recipes, using the single recipe component. The reason why I split both up into separate components is that I want the component that maps the different recipes, to be reused to also map the favorite recipes from the user (avoiding writing additional code to basically do the same process, namely rendering an array with different recipes in it).

For saving the favorite recipes I wanted to use redux since this (from what I understand) allows me to dispatch the state to different components (using mapStateToProps and connect). This should allow me (correct me if I am wrong) to use the state of the favoriteRecipes in the components which maps the different recipes. I can also use the state in the single recipe component to create a button for adding the different recipes to my favorites. For one or another reason I can just not get the dispatch/redux to work. In the redux devtools I can see the initial state (an empty array) but once I try to add a recipe to the favoriteRecipe array nothing happens. I have tried to get it working for a few days now, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

First file: /redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesTypes.js

```
export const ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES = 'ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES';
export const REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES = 'REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES';
export const CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES = 'CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES';
```

Second action creators: /redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesActions/js

```
import { ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES, REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES, CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES  } from "./favoriteRecipesTypes";

export const addToFavoriteRecipes = (recipe) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES,
        payload: recipe
    }
}

export const removeFromFavoriteRecipes = (recipe) => {
    return {
        type: REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES,
        payload: recipe
    }
}

export const clearFavoriteRecipes = () => {
    return{
        type: CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES
    }
}
```

Third the reducer: /redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesReducer.js

```
import { ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES, REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES, CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES  } from "./favoriteRecipesTypes";

const initialFavoriteRecipes = {
    favoriteRecipes: []
}

const favoriteRecipesReducer = (state = initialFavoriteRecipes, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_FAVORITE_RECIPES:
            return {
                ...state,
                favoriteRecipes: [...state.favoriteRecipes, action.payload]
            }
        case REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE_RECIPES: 
            return {
                ...state,
                favoriteRecipes: state.favoriteRecipes.filter(item => item !== action.payload)
            }
        case CLEAR_FAVORITE_RECIPES:
            return {
                ...state,
                favoriteRecipes: []
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}


export default favoriteRecipesReducer;
```

Fourth the store: /redux/store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import favoriteRecipesReducer from "../redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesReducer";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const store = 
createStore(
    favoriteRecipesReducer, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(logger), 
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
        )
)
    


export default store;
```

Fifth: the individual recipe component (I omitted some parts to keep this as short as possible):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addToFavoriteRecipes } from '../../redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesActions';

export const Recipe = ({recipe}, props) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="col-md-3">
            <div className="card bwm-card">
                <div className="card-title">
                    <h2>{recipe.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <img className="card-img-top" src={recipe.image} alt={recipe.title} />
                <div className="card-subtitle">
                    <h3>
                        <b>Type: {recipe.type} </b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        <b>Category: {recipe.category}</b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        <b>Cooking time: {recipe.cookingTime} minutes</b>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div>//omitted part: show or hide full recipe depending on the state of isOpen</div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" onClick={props.addToFavoriteRecipes} value="add to favorite recipe" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        favoriteRecipes: state.favoriteRecipes
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        addToFavoriteRecipes: () => dispatch(addToFavoriteRecipes())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Recipe)
```

Comment: Generally please note that you are using a very old style of Redux there. Modern Redux uses hooks instead of connect and has no switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic or createStore. Check the official Redux tutorial https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts for more into.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers!

Just after I posed the question I got it working like this.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addToFavoriteRecipes } from '../../redux/favoriteRecipes/favoriteRecipesActions';
import store from '../../redux/store';

export const Recipe = ({recipe}) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="col-md-3">
            <div className="card bwm-card">
                <div className="card-title">
                    <h2>{recipe.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <img className="card-img-top" src={recipe.image} alt={recipe.title} />
                <div className="card-subtitle">
                    <h3>
                        <b>Type: {recipe.type} </b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        <b>Category: {recipe.category}</b>
                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                        <b>Cooking time: {recipe.cookingTime} minutes</b>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {isOpen ? (
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="card-body-ingredient">
                                {recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient, i) => {
                                    return (
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                <th>Ingredient</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>{ingredient[0]}</th>
                                                <th>{ingredient[1]}</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-body-cookingsteps">
                                {recipe.cookingSteps.map((cookingstep, i) => {
                                    return <p>{cookingstep}</p>;
                                })}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    value="Hide full recipe"
                                    onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
                                    Hide full recipe
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            value="Show full recipe"
                            onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                            Show full recipe
                        </button>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" onClick={() => store.dispatch(addToFavoriteRecipes(recipe))} value="add to favorite recipe" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Just seems to defeat the entire purpose of working with mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of does when you import the store object and directly dispatch actions to it. It will work but I think it's generally considered anti-pattern to do so instead of using the `mapDispatchToProps` or `useDispatch` hook. With function components it is recommended to use the `useDispatch` hook. Similarly with using the `useSelector` hook to select the state. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

React components receive only a single props argument, but you are attempting to destructure the action from a second, undefined argument. Both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, like their name implies, maps these values onto the `props` object. They can be destructured from the `props` object.

```
export const Recipe = ({
  addToFavoriteRecipes, // <-- destructure from props
  recipe,
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <div className="card bwm-card">
        <div className="card-title">
          <h2>{recipe.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <img className="card-img-top" src={recipe.image} alt={recipe.title} />
        <div className="card-subtitle">
          <h3>
            <b>Type: {recipe.type}</b>
          </h3>
          <h3>
            <b>Category: {recipe.category}</b>
          </h3>
          <h3>
            <b>Cooking time: {recipe.cookingTime} minutes</b>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          // omitted part: show or hide full recipe depending on the state of isOpen
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            onClick={addToFavoriteRecipes} // <-- pass as callback
            value="add to favorite recipe"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```